# draft.push is not a function onCacheEntryAdded in redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Trying to update my cache by pushing new data into existing data but I am not able to mutate draft and getting error draft.push is not a function

```
async onCacheEntryAdded(
  arg,
  { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }
) {
  try {
    await cacheDataLoaded
    await connected

    client.on("message", (topic, data) => {
      const message = JSON.parse(data.toString())
      console.log("message", message.payload)
      updateCachedData((draft) => {
        if (!message.payload) return
        draft.push(message.payload)
      })
    })
  } catch (err) {

  }

  await cacheEntryRemoved
},
```

Comment: The most likely issue is that your `draft` is storing something other than an `array`.  Throw in a `console.log(current(draft));` and see what you have.

Comment: oh yes, the issue was draft was not an array. 
The reason I was confused was that the draft was showing in bits and pieces and there was no data visualization. Thanks for the help @LindaPaiste